# IC identification - Analog Devices with top marking S BB

Tags: operational-amplifier, identification

Please help me to identify this IC. I guess it is an Analog Devices chip.

The top marking says "S BB".  I think it's an op-amp and it's used in a current probe.

Thank you!

[image: photo of the unknown IC on a PCB]

Comment: Can you make some better pictures with better lighting from different angles? Its hard with just these 3 Letters - do one exactly from above also.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this is the chip you seek: -

[image]

Comment: [ADG419 analog switch datasheet.](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG419.pdf)